# How to use add_definititions() variable inside c++ classes?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have defined a couple of variables in my CMakeLists.txt like so:

```
# the subject of the commit
execute_process(
  COMMAND git log -1 --format=%s
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
  OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT
  ERROR_QUIET OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
)

add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT=${GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT}")
```

How could I access the `GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT` inside my classes?

Like so:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT = %s \n", GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT);
}
```

Comment: Have you *tried* the code you show? What problems do you have with it? What is the expected result? What is the actual result? What is the value of the CMake variable `GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT`? Is it a string? A number? Something else? Also please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) as well as how to [edit] your questions.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant if there is a way to stringify those macros, so I could display them in a single log. My question was bad, should I delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define macros as strings when building, but you need to enclose the strings in double-quotes:

```
add_definitions("-DGIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT=\"${GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT}\"")
```

Now any use of the macro `GIT_COMMIT_SUBJECT` inside the code will be replace by a literal string.